# java get image using connection.getInputStream

Tags: java

Is it possible to get an image from a website using Connection.getInputStream? I have a website (http://xxxxx.php) with an image on it that I want to recieve using Connection.getInputStream. Is there a way to achieve this?

I have the following code:

```
URL url= new URL("http://xxxxx.php");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

I need to get

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to add it to my application

Comment: What do you want to do with it in your application? What kind of object are you going to use? What is it going to do? The binary data is there, but the question is - what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: I want to dispay the image in my GUI, in a JPanel

Comment: You can use
`URL url = new URL("Your URL");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);`

Comment: Assuming that xxx.php is returning HTML, then you'd need to parse the HTML and extract the <img> tags, then you can use the src attribute to get the url for the image itself...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your PHP script is actually returning an image, then what you do, at least for a reasonably-sized image, is open it with `javax.imageio.ImageIO`, which is a class containing utility methods for reading images - from a file, from a stream, etc.

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://xxxxx.php/");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        // Pass the input stream thorough a BufferedInputStream for better
        // efficiency
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        // Read the image and close the stream
        Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
        is.close();

        if (image == null) {
            System.err.println("ImageIO could not find a reader for this image");
        } else {

            // Display GUI
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To avoid problems, make sure that the PHP script is sending the appropriate MIME type (`image/jpeg`,`image/gif`,`image/png` etc.).

---

If you meant that your PHP script is returning an HTML that has an `IMG` tag somewhere on it, then you'll need to parse it, using, for example, [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Based on your knowledge of the structure of the HTML, you'll

- Find the appropriate `IMG` tag
- Extract the URL from its `SRC` attribute.
- If the URL is relative (does not start with `http://`, `https://` etc.), you'll need to append it to the base URL of the PHP script.
- Then use the above code to display the image from the resulting URL.

Note that if the creator of that site decides to change his design, your program will stop working. If you have a better way to locate the image you need without reading HTML (for example, using an API or web service), it would be much better.

Comment: This assumes that xxx.php returns image data, if it doesn't, then it won't work

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is why there is an `if (image == null)` there. If the stream is not an image stream, `ImageIO.read()` returns `null`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah, I see what you mean. You think that the OP is asking about an image embedded in an HTML page. I'll qualify my answer regarding that.